# EFI Partition Change name and Logo

Tags: partition, startup, ssd, efi

I've installed Windows again but this time on a external SSD.
it's all working fine, but when holding the alt/option key it's giving me Macintosh HD and EFI partition.
how can I change this name "EFI Partition" and its logo?
the logo is a orange one.
and I also want it to show up in system preferences startup selector on mac OSX.
it's only showing me Macintosh HD.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The icon displayed in the Mac Startup Manager can be changed by putting an icon set file named `.VolumeIcon.icns` in the root folder of the EFI partition used by Windows. Or, you can follow the instructions at the end of this answer.

A png file can be converted to icons file by using the commands `sips` and `iconutil`. A script for doing this is given below.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
if [[ $0 != "$BASH_SOURCE" ]]; then
    bash "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
    return
fi

Convert() {
    local -i "n=${1%%x*}"
    [[ $1 != *@2x ]] || n="2*n"
    sips -s format png -z "$n" "$n" "$full" --out "$name.iconset/icon_$1.png"
}

Main() {
    local "full=$1"
    local "base=$(basename "$full")"
    local "name=${base%.*}"
    rm -rf "$name.iconset"
    mkdir "$name.iconset"
    Convert "16x16"
    Convert "16x16@2x"
    Convert "32x32"
    Convert "32x32@2x"
    Convert "128x128"
    Convert "128x128@2x"
    Convert "256x256"
    Convert "256x256@2x"
    Convert "512x512"
    Convert "512x512@2x"
    iconutil -c icns "$name.iconset"
    rm -r "$name.iconset"
}
set -u
Main "$@"
```

For example, if you were to download this [Windows 10 logo png file](https://www.cleanpng.com/png-logo-microsoft-cyan-5112543/preview.html) to the same folder as the script file, then the command given below would replace the png file with a icns file. Here, the script file is named `createicns` and `Windows10.png` is the png file. The result would be the creation a `Windows10.icns` file, which you would rename `.VolumeIcon.icns`.

```
./createicns Windows10.png
```

> You can also download icns files for various operating systems from [this website](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mac-icns/). I converted the [Windows 10 logo png file](https://www.cleanpng.com/png-logo-microsoft-cyan-5112543/preview.html) and posted [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mac-icns/files/PreviousVersions/3-1-2016/) for download. The file name is `Windows10.icns`.

The label displayed in the Mac Startup Manager can be changed by using the `bless` command. Assuming `diskutil list` shows your external drive is `disk2` and the EFI partition is first on the drive, then command below would mount this partition.

```
sudo diskutil mount disk2s1
```

Assuming the EFI volume is labeled `EFI`, then the command below would change the label to `Windows`.

```
bless --folder /Volumes/EFI/efi/boot --label "Windows"
```

This command creates the two hidden files given below.

```
.disk_label
.disk_label_2x
```

Afterwards, the command given below can unmount the EFI partition.

```
diskutil unmount disk2s1
```

The Start Disk pane in System Preferences may not shown an Windows installation on an external drive. Or, if the installation does appear, you may not be able to successfully select the installation. AFAIK there is no fix for this.

There is an alternative where [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) can be used to select the default operation system directly from Windows, macOS and most Linux installations. However this requires installing a GUI script in each operation system as well as installing and configuring rEFInd.

### Contents of an `icns` File

The contents of a `icns` file can vary depending on the version of OS X or macOS you are using. The table below can be used to compare the differences between an `icns` file create using El Capitan (OS X 10.11.6) and one created using Catalina (MacOS 10.15.4). Both files were creating using the same script as given above. The descriptions came from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Icon_Image_format).

| 10.11 | 10.15 | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X |  | `s8mk` | 16x16 8-bit mask |
| X |  | `is32` | 16×16 24-bit icon |
|  | X | `ic04` | 16x16 ARGB |
| X | X | `ic11` | 16x16@2x "retina" icon in JPEG 2000 or PNG format |
| X |  | `l8mk` | 32×32 8-bit mask |
| X |  | `il32` | 32x32 24-bit icon |
|  | X | `ic05` | 32x32 ARGB |
| X | X | `ic12` | 32x32@2x "retina" icon in JPEG 2000 or PNG format |
| X |  | `t8mk` | 128×128 8-bit mask |
| X |  | `it32` | 128×128 24-bit icon |
|  | X | `ic07` | 128x128 icon in JPEG 2000 or PNG format |
| X | X | `ic13` | 128x128@2x "retina" icon in JPEG 2000 or PNG format |
| X | X | `ic08` | 256×256 icon in JPEG 2000 or PNG format |
| X | X | `ic14` | 256x256@2x "retina" icon in JPEG 2000 or PNG format |
| X | X | `ic09` | 512×512 icon in JPEG 2000 or PNG format |
| X | X | `ic10` | 1024×1024 in 10.7 (or 512x512@2x "retina" in 10.8) icon in JPEG 2000 or PNG format |
| X |  | `name` | Unknown |
|  | X | `info` | Info binary plist. Usage unknown |

> Note: The `icns` files produced using Catalina appeared to only work with the firmware included with newer Intel Macs. The `icns` files produced using El Capitan appeared to work with the firmware included with all Intel Macs. I wrote *"appeared"*, because I could not test on all Intel Macs.

A script, that can print out the types in a `icns` file, can be found in the file `Notes.dmg`, which is part of the [Mac icons](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mac-icns/files/) project.

### How to Install the icns File

Enter the command `diskutil list` to determine the EFI partition where the Windows 10 boot files are stored. On my Mac, I get this:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         800.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data Fish1                   98.0 GB    disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                91.5 GB    disk0s4
   5:       Microsoft Basic Data Fish2                   10.5 GB    disk0s5

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +800.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Muskie                  32.2 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 107.2 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.0 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      8.6 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Snapper - Data          660.0 GB   disk1s5
   6:                APFS Volume Snapper                 11.2 GB    disk1s6

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk2s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                499.9 GB   disk2s3
```

The only external drive is `disk2`. The only `EFI` partition on this drive is `disk2s1`, so this is where the Windows 10 boot files are stored. The command below will mount the volume stored in this partition.

```
sudo diskutil mount disk2s1
```

This volume appears in the Finder as `EFI`. If I right click on the the volume and select `Get Info`, the following window appears.

[image]

To install the `.icns` file, drag the file and drop over the icon in the upper left corner of this window, as shown below.

[image]

The result is shown below.

[image]

The `.VolumeIcon.icns` file normally does not appear in the Finder. To view hidden files in the Finder, the key combination <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> needs to be pressed. The image below shows all the files and folders in the root folder of the volume in the EFI partition.

[image]

Finally, enter the command below to unmount the EFI volume.

```
diskutil unmount disk2s1
```

### References

[Create a Set of Icons That Includes High-Resolution Versions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH7-SW4)
[Use iconutil to Create an icns File Manually](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH7-SW2)
[Apple Icon Image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Icon_Image_format)
[SourceForge Mac icns Project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mac-icns/)

Comment: Thanks Again David!
I managed to change the name with the terminal lines you gave me, but to change the logo I need a little bit of help. I don't really understand the script lines you gave me. sorry.

Comment: Do you know what image you want to use as and icon in the Startup Manager? I can create the `.icns` file and make the file available for download.

Comment: The one you named "Windows 10 logo png file" what you supplied earlier is awesome I think.

Comment: I put the file `Windows10.icns` on SourceForge. You can go [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mac-icns/files/) to download the file.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still don't get it, the link you send isn't that the same as earlier? From ReFind

Comment: Maybe, but I just added the `Windows10.icns` file. I am the user davidanderson61 at SourceForge. I created the project "Mac icns".

Comment: okay I downloaded the file, what do I have to do with it?

Comment: I got multiple windows logo's into I think different sizes... opened in preview

Comment: Where do I put the Windows10.icns file

Comment: The letters `icns` stands for icon set. The computer picks which icon in the set to use.

Comment: You copy the file to the root of the EFI volume used to boot Windows. You then rename the file to the name `.VolumeIcon.icns`.

Comment: so I have to mount the EFI partition again? in which folder? EFI, Microsoft or Boot.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer. Does this help you install the `Windows10.icns` file?