# How do I change the icons and labels in the MacOS boot manager?

Tags: bootcamp, startup, big-sur

I freshly installed Big Sur with Windows 10 Boot Camp on a late-2013 MacBook Pro Retina with a replaced SSD. When I hold down the option button at boot, the options are listed as "EFI Boot" (Windows 10) and "Macintosh HD", but both are using external drive icons instead of internal. Under MacOS, the icons for both drives appear correctly as internal drives. I tried changing drive names in diskutil, renaming the drives in the MacOS Disk Utility and under Windows, placing .VolumeIcon.icns files in various places, and various bless commands.

I'm asking this to answer my own question, I couldn't quite find a correct solution in any one spot. Pay close attention to the folders involved, this was the important part.

Comment: Are you using encryption anywhere?

Comment: FileVault was turned on, and SIP was enabled.  Nothing on the Windows side.  I think this problem happened at least partially because I'd replaced the SSD (with an M.2 NVMe device).  In the solution below I mentioned that SIP should be turned off with csrutil.

Answer (score 2):

**Rename “EFI Boot” in Startup Manager:**

Open up a Terminal and use the following commands:

`diskutil list` - use this to find the Windows EFI partition

`sudo diskutil mount disk0s1` - whereas "disk0s1" is your EFI partition

`sudo bless --folder /Volumes/EFI/EFI/Boot --label Windows` - whereas "Windows" is your label of choice

**Rename “Macintosh HD” in Startup Manager**

Similar to above, but:

`sudo bless --folder /System/Volumes/Data --label MacOS` - whereas "MacOS" is your label of choice

**Missing/Wrong Boot Manager Icon**

Reboot in recovery mode (command+R at boot) and use a terminal to run

`csrutil disable`
… which disables SIP protection

For Mac side:

`sudo cp /System/Library/Extensions/IOStorageFamily.kext/Contents/Resources/Internal.icns /System/Volumes/Preboot/.VolumeIcon.icns`

This will change the Mac/Macintosh HD boot icon to the default internal drive icon, but you can just copy whatever .icns file you wish to that location.  See other posts for info on making your own .icns files.

For Windows side:

`sudo diskutil mount disk0s1` - Whereas disk01 is the name of your Windows EFI partition from above

`sudo cp /System/Library/Extensions/IOStorageFamily.kext/Contents/Resources/Internal.icns /Volumes/EFI/.VolumeIcon.icns`

Don't forget to enable SIP protection again, if you wish, by booting back into recovery mode and using:

`csrutil enable`

Comment: It specifically relates to Big Sur.  I did mention the bit about making .icns files elsewhere - there's a good post on it here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388246/efi-partition-change-name-and-logo

Comment: Sorry, I read your answer several times before posting my (now deleted) comment. I should have also read the question. Clearly, your question and answer is for a late-2013 MacBook Pro Retina with a Big Sur and Windows 10 dual boot.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for parfpony,
I have just few comments about BigSur 11.1

1. If anyone face the problem that the following command is not changing the "windows" to new the volume label "WIN", after mounting EFI volume :

sudo bless --folder /Volumes/EFI/EFI/Boot --label WIN

just replace the "label" by "file", that is ..

sudo bless --folder /Volumes/EFI/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi --file WIN

or

sudo bless --folder /Volumes/EFI/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi --file "WIN 10"

*quotes*  are used in case your new label(WIN 10) contains spaces.

2. Related to Icon replacement it can be done easily by using old method without
   using any scripts or terminal command (for both Mac and windows volumes):

   a.  Use Finder preferences --> General ---> Show hard disk, to display your
   volumes on desktop.

   b.  Select “Macintosh HD” Volume (MacOS volume) then use right click --> “Get
   Info”--> select the small hard disk image located in upper left corner.

   c.  Choose any icon, with an extension *.icns and NOT Jpeg or PNG images, and
   drag it on the small image (step b), you will see that the desktop volume
   icon is automatically changed.

   d.  You can use “image2icon” application from apple store to convert your
   favourite images to icons (1024X1024 pixel) with an extension “.icns”.
3. If you installed "BigSur 11.1" from scratch or clean install, the account name
   chosen will be the macOS volume name displayed directly in boot start up
   manager and no need for renaming.

   So Easy !!!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for that.  I found that dragging the icon to the "Get Info" window wouldn't work for me for whatever reason.  It would show the icons I wanted (the internal drive icons), but they wouldn't appear in the boot manager until I manually placed them in the folders specified above.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get paragraph 1 (renaming Windows volume in Startup Manager) to work on 2019 16-inch MacBook Pro ([my question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/444554/)) and macOS Big Sur 11.6.5. Maybe there's a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

barfpony, I really appreciate your help! You made me sign up for StackExchange to leave this comment & supplementing answer for others searching for Google.

1. If the terminal command written above is not working, try disabling SIP first. As barfpony mentioned, press command (⌘)+R at boot and enter Recovery mode. Open terminal, and type `csrutil disable` to turn SIP off.
2. Reboot, and login to your macOS account. Then, open Terminal.
3. Try typing in the Terminal commands written by barfpony.

   **3-A. Changing the label of 'Macintosh HD'**

   `sudo bless --folder /System/Volumes/Data --label macOS` - whereas "MacOS" is your label of choice

   **3-B. Changing the icon of 'Macintosh HD'**

   `sudo cp (location of the new icon) /System/Volumes/Preboot/.VolumeIcon.icns`

   This command will change the default disk icon to the new icon. If it is hard for you to type the location of the new icon, just **drag-and-drop the new icon** into terminal window. This will generate the location of the file automatically.
4. Once its done, reboot and press and hold the option (⌥) to check the new label and icon appears.
5. If you succeeded, do not choose either macOS or Windows disk; press command (⌘)+R. This will open Recovery Mode.
6. Once Recovery mode is on, open Terminal again, then type `csrutil enable` to turn SIP on again.

Everything I have written was tested on macOS Big Sur 11.1, with 16-inch MacBook Pro (2019). However, I did not test changing the EFI boot partition since my BOOTCAMP disk did not have the same issue.

Thanks again, barfpony.

Comment: Hey ryubellone, would you kindly double-check if you can change label of your **BOOTCAMP** volume displayed in Startup Manager? I use similar laptop and absolutely cannot change it for the Boot Camp volume on my laptop's **internal** SSD. [Here's my question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/444554/) with [photo example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abScJ.jpg).