# Change boot option icons

Tags: macos, bootcamp, unix

I have a Mid 2012 MacBook Pro with  two hard drives with a triple boot system High Sierra Windows 10 and Ubuntu. High sierra is on the SSD while windows and Ubuntu share another drive.

[image]

Would like to set an icon for each operation system. I have followed some guides on here but not getting through. For Ubuntu...it shows up as a EFI BOOT. I did remember that upon installation of Ubuntu...I have placed the bootloader in Dev/sd1...same location as the EFI volume for windows. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: "followed some guides" Please specify what guides, what you did & what the results were. Also consider you should post your Terminal results as formatted text not as an image - these cannot be searched in Google & cannot be read by tools for the vision-impaired.

Comment: Ok so sorry. Will do now

Answer (score 1):

I can not precisely determine how your Mac is configured. Here is what you are claiming:

- You have two HDDs, one SSD and apparently a fourth drive on some kind.
- High Sierra is installed on the SSD.
- Both Windows and Ubuntu are installed on the drive of a kind yet to be revealed.
- Apparently both Windows and Ubuntu are installed to UEFI boot from the same drive even though the drive is using a MBR partition map. This is a rather unusual configuration.
- You have followed some guides of unknown origin. Specifying the guides might provide some useful information.
- I do not think `Dev/sd1` actually exists.

So instead of offering a specific answer to your question, I will instead provide some general information regarding how to customize the Mac Startup Manager icons. First, the same name is used for each icon file. This name is `.VolumeIcon.icns`. Each icon file is stored in the root directory of the volume that contains the boot file. If two or more operating systems share the same volume  for their boot file, then they share the same icon. When macOS is installed in an APFS container, the macOS boots from the `Preboot` volume. In the case of a UEFI booting Windows or Ubuntu, this would normally be FAT32 volume stored in a EFI partition. If an operating system BIOS boots, then the icon can not be customized.

To create a custom `icns` file, see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388246/efi-partition-change-name-and-logo/388287#388287).