# What is the easiest way to generate an ICNS file from a single image, but with it32 for at least the 128x128? (macos)

Tags: macos

I'm making new icons for all my disks/partitions (all macos).
All the apps/scripts I've tried, output the 128x128 as "ic07".
None of the other sizes within the ICNS file have an issue with type, but 128x128 is the size that displays during boot up, and it WILL NOT display "ic07".
Looking at sample ICNS that WILL load during boot up, and they are all icon type "it32".

The simplest ICNS creating apps I have found ask for a single image input, then spit out a completed ICNS.  **I was hoping to find one that outputs the 128x128 within the ICNS as "it32"** (or other type that WILL show during boot).  I'm not concerned about any of the other sizes' icon type yet.

Or, I don't know if this is possible, **is there a way to configure the input image, so the output ICNS is automatically built with "it32"?**

Thanks

Comment: This [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388246/efi-partition-change-name-and-logo/388287#388287) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a pro in icons, but you should take a look at [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) to get this done.
If you're not familiar of what Homebrew is, it's a package manager for apps/software.

Doing a quick search, there are two apps in homebrew that seem to be able to generate ICNS: [libicns](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/libicns) and [makeicns](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/makeicns).

The `makeicns` seems to do the job (tried locally). First you'd need to install the package with

```
brew install makeicns
```

Then the syntax to make a 32x32 icon in `makeicns` is:

```
makeicns -32 image.png
```

Which creates image.icns with only a 32x32 variant. I've tried locally and go a 32x32 .icns file.

Comment: Installed Homebrew.  Installing libicns, but maybe I am 2 OS versions too old for libicns, unless they have older versios that can be downloaded.I looked quick and didn't see anything.  Seems to be stuck at "make" in terminal anyway.  MakeICNS.  I can probably redo on my Bg Sur drive insteadand tray again,  bt I have some tasks running right now.

Comment: ok, it LOOKS like makeicns will work, as it creates "il32" for 128x128, but wht the heck is "otherfile.png"?

Comment: Where do you see "otherfile.png"?

Comment: when you type MAKEICNS into Terminal, at the end of the data that returns, are 2 example commands.  The 2nd example  includes a placeholder labeled "otherfile.png".

Comment: ```makeicns -in myfile.jpg -32 otherfile.png -out outfile.icns ``` :
Creates outfile.icns with sizes 512, 256, 128, and 16 containing data from `myfile.jpg` and with size 32 containing data from `otherfile.png` . 

This is only used if you want to use another image to make one of the other sizes.