# Change EFI label for external volume

Tags: startup, efi, sd-card, bless

I am booting a retrogaming system (Recalbox, linux-based) on my Macbook Pro 2009 (Intel, El Capitan) from an SD card (FAT format).

The SD card is currently displayed as "EFI boot" upon boot drive selection (*al*t key upon startup), as it currently displays "EFI boot". I would like to change that label ("RECALBOX", for example).

I have been through many ressources online and tried the `bless` command as advised here:
[EFI Partition Change name and Logo](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388246/efi-partition-change-name-and-logo)

My version:

`bless --folder /Volumes/RECALBOX/EFI/boot --label "RECALBOX"`

It does create the expected hidden files in the folder

`.disk_label`
`.disk_label_2x`

but the default "EFI boot" label doesn't change in the boot selection on startup.

Any ideas if I'm missing something?

Thanks for your help!